# Scrollable ListView and a TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm little confused playin arround with android layout files.
What I wan't to get is this:
http://img857.imageshack.us/img857/5939/examplen.jpg

Remember that ListView area is scrollable, but the TextView should be always visible on the screen, no matter how long is the list.

I tried several methods, last was like:

```
<LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout>
     <ListView>
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout>
     <TextView>
  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I can't get it work properly. Maybe I got a wrong approach, or just the settings are wrong?
I'll upload whole xml code if my approach is correct and this is the matter of setings

Comment: soo u have the solution or do u wanna have ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/textView" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Wow, thats what i call an answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

use Relative layout as container

here is the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/row1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <TextView android:text="This is bottom text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_above="@id/row1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"></ListView>
    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: haven't done that one yet. Documentation says it should do the trick. I'll check it out later and accept the answer if it works

Answer (score 0):

Use Following Layout Helps you.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" >
</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="TextView" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```